# Initializing C# DayOfWeek Enum

Tags: c#, enums, initialization, dayofweek

According to the MSDN doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DayOfWeek.aspx), each member of the Enum can be cast to `Int` to get a corresponding 0-indexed value. But I want to convert an `Int` value, ranging from 0 to 6, to this Enum.

How is this possible?

Comment: 0-7 contains 8 numbers! There are only 7 week days :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast it in reverse:

```
int intValue = 1;
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)intValue;
```

Comment: enums aren't really anything more than syntax sugar for integer constants. You can assign a value to them which is outside of the defined values and they'll happily accept it, possibly causing issues for your app down the line. Always verify.